# Creating a path for a php file generates path not found error

Tags: symfony

When I try to create a path variable:

```
{% block jquery %} 
      <script>var url = "{{ path('bundles/foo/ajax/widb-get-data.php') }}";</script>
{% endblock %}
```

I get the following error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "FooBundle:Default:myfile.php" as such route does not exist.")
```

Comment: If you are using Symfony should you be using a route and not a specific php file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, I'm new to Symfony, can you please elaborate?

Comment: A route points to a method in a controller which generates a response. This is the same for a viewable page as it is for one that you would use for ajax. It seems that you need  to read up on [controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html) and [routing](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html).

Comment: @hcoat, I am aware of this. However, I was not aware that controllers take on the responsibility of AJAX. So what you mean is, everything that relied on AJAX to generate a response, should be generated by controller, using Symfony, for good practice?

Comment: Yes, this is good practice.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/README.markdown)

you can then do :

```
<script>
    var url = Routing.generate('route_id', /* your params */);
</script>
```

Note that you are calling a **route** not a **file**

In order to call a route declared in your controller by `routing.generate`, be sure to expose it before :

```
/**
 * @Route("/foo/{id}/bar", name="my_route_to_expose", options={"expose"=true})
 */
public function exposedAction($foo)
```